# Unable to fetch data from API present in the On-Prem server and display it in an SharePoint Online Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an requirement to fetch the data from API present in the on-Prem server and display it in an SharePoint Online Page.
Sample URL: https://myserver.net/api/issue-number/
OUTPUT in JSON format: {"OPEN ISSUE": 1000, "CREATED ISSUE": 230, "CLOSED ISSUE": 260}
Accessing the URL in the browser displays the output in JSON format.
I tried using JSNOP but unable to get the data. 
Can someone tell me how can achieve this?